# Webpack inject.preload.js file not found

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, vue.js

I use Vue/Typscript with webpack. And everytime i open page `inject.preload.js` throws an error like `GET blob:http://URL/1fbc0606-8477-416b-a45f-50b4d824f2bb 0 ()` and i don't know where it comes from or why something got inject.

I tested it on Google Chrome Incognito mode and Firefox there is no error thrown.

How can i find out why this error occurs?

[Console ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdOWY.png)

**package.json**

```
    {
      ...

      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "email-validator": "^1.1.1",
        "generate-password": "^1.3.0",
        "grunt": "^1.0.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "moment": "^2.22.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.17",
        "promise-polyfill": "^7.1.2",
        "vue-axios": "^2.0.2",
        "vue-class-component": "^6.2.0",
        "vue-cloneya": "^1.0.5",
        "vue-property-decorator": "^6.0.0",
        "vue-spinner": "^1.0.3",
        "vuex": "^3.0.1",
        "vuex-class": "^0.3.0",
        "invert-color": "^1.2.3",
        "vuejs-datepicker": ""
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^9.4.7",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
        "eslint": "^4.19.1",
        "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.3",
        "eslint-plugin-typescript": "^0.11.0",
        "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.4.1",
        "grunt-git-describe": "^2.4.2",
        "grunt-open": "^0.2.3",
        "grunt-shell": "^2.1.0",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "i": "^0.3.6",
        "ts-loader": "^2.3.7",
        "typescript": "2.7.2",
        "typescript-eslint-parser": "^14.0.0",
        "typings": "^2.1.1",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.16",
        "vue-loader": "^14.2.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.15",
        "webpack": "^3.11.0",
        "webpackbar": "^2.6.1"
      }

      ...
   }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './templates/src/app.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.(js|ts|vue)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'templates/src')
                ],
                loader: 'eslint-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
                        // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
                        // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
                        'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
                        'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax',
                    }
                    // other vue-loader options go here
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ 'vue-style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.json', '.html'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: true
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    devtool: '#eval-source-map'
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.devtool = '#source-map';
    // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"'
            }
        }),
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            sourceMap: true
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true
        })
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The error occurs because of AdBlock extension. To verify you can **fully** disable the extension in chrome://extensions/ url.

Comment: weird that it happens even if I disable add blocker for the domain.  Have to fully disable the extension for it to go away

Comment: Indeed. I've updated the answer.