# I am getting blob errors in my console, how can i track them down, so I can fix them?

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, blob

Hello there I am using Chrome and I am getting those errors when loading my website:

```
inject.preload.js:373 GET blob:https://pechatnaknigi.test/f52e1770-ef12-4832-99ee-b93a7eed9794 0 ()
inject.preload.js:373 GET blob:https://www.google.com/f94a9698-9990-4d0c-aab7-fb2cf564cd55 0 ()
```

Why are those errors showing and how can I track them down in order to fix them? I don't have a file with a name of inject.preload.js, so I guess it is created automatically when the website is loading. I have seen this error

> **GET blob:[url] 0 ()**

and to some other websites, I am managing as well.

Thanks!

Comment: check your add-ons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling AdBlock: `chrome://extensions/`. There are [other posts on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50866084/123033) so although your question may be a duplicate, there's so much cruft on the others answers that this is worth preserving.

Comment: after disabling AdBlock only for this domain now i don't see the errors anymore.

Comment: actually now i saw that i am still receiving blob errors even after disabling Ghostery, Privacy Badger and AdBlocker :(

Comment: and some of the blob errors have turn into: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()`

Comment: 500 is an internal server error, and the Binary Large Object error looks like a binary file isn’t being found, so without further details it’s hard to comment. take a look at more detailed error messages in the terminal or error logs from your server...